# How take var from 2 identical form

Tags: jquery, html

I have two (2) identical forms on the same page and when I try get same var form the second form, but always get var from the first.

```
<form id="form-vote-note-<?php echo $value->id_note; ?>" class="form-vote-note" method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="idvote" id="idvote" value="<?php echo $value->id_note; ?>">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="voteradio" id="voteradio" value="3">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="voteradio" id="voteradio" value="2">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Oceń</button>
</form>

$('#form-vote-note').submit(function() {

            var notevote = $('input:radio[name=voteradio]:checked').val();
            var idvote = $('input[name=idvote]').val();
            alert("notevote: " + notevote + " --- idvote: " + idvote);

            //alert("Ocena: " + notevote + "\nId vote: " + idvote);
            $.ajax ({
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>database/save_vote_note/",
                type: "POST",
                data: {idvote: idvote, notevote: notevote, id_product: <?php echo $id_product;?>},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {

                    alert("Id vote:" + data.value['idvote'] + "\n voteradio: " + data.value['notevote'] + "\n id_product:" + data.value['id_product'])
                },
                error: function() {

                },
            });
        });
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. And why do you have two identical forms on the same page anyway?

Comment: your form needs to use `method` not `metod` (just a pointed) however ids must be unique. Your error lies there

Comment: I want create website where users can vote for products. I 
generates three forms via php.

Comment: lets rephrase this. Your form ID must be unique, form can be the same.

Comment: I know I must have identical forms. But sometimes php will generate more than 2 forms. How create good code of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of methods of generating unique references when creating HTML via PHP loops.

1. Use a counter, and add the counter to the ID:

```
    <?php
        $cnt = 1;
        while (condition){
           $out .= '<input id="unique_' .$cnt. '" type="text" />';
           $cnt++;
        }
```

2. Use a class. There is really never a need to use IDs at all. On the other hand, it is slightly more difficult to get the unique identifier from a className if the element has multiple classes. So, you can use a common prefix:

Then you can loop though all input tags that have a className that contains the prefix.

```
$('input').each(function(i, v){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('[class^="unique"]') ){
        var allCls = $(this).attr('class');
        var targCls = get_targ_from_all_class(); //loop thru classes and return the one with prefix
        var uniqID = targCls.split('_')[1]
    }
});
```